# Is there a way to populate date values across multiple slides?

Tags: powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I have a presentation template used for monthly status meetings. The title slide of the template contains MONTH, where, as you may be able to tell is where the user of the template enters the month of the meeting :)

There are other slides with the titles:
Plan for MONTH
Completions in MONTH
Shortcomings in MONTH

Is there a way to populate MONTH onto the slides once I type it on the title slide? I am looking for a non-vba answer if possible, but if that is the only way, I am willing to learn vba for powerpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to accomplish this sans-VBA by putting the date into a cell in Excel.  Select and copy the cell contents, then switch to PPT and Paste Special, Link to put the text into PPT.

Repeat for each instance where you need Month to be replaced (Paste Linking the same cell from Excel).

Each month, edit the Excel cel to contain the new month, then open the PPT, which should update to the new month wherever you've linked it in.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but I am trying to create the template to provide simplification, and I worry introducing excel, would be more complicated. While what you are saying is not complicated and very simple, it just introduces another application.

Do you know if it can be done via VBA in PPT? I ask because no other responses have come in. Thanks.

Comment: VBA could do this, but it occurs to me that you could have users start with a new presentation based on a template, one that contains all the needed slides and "@MONTH@" (literally, but w/o the quotes) wherever you need the current month.  All they'd have to is use PPT's Search/Replace feature (from the ribbon or just press Ctrl+H) to search on @MONTH@ and replace it with December or whatever.  Why the @ signs?  So that they don't inadvertently replace the word month in places where it shouldn't be replaced:  This month's sales becomes This December's sales, for example.

Comment: Hi Steve, yeah, that is what my template instructions say, and I was just hoping to take it to "the next step" for the end user.

Comment: It'd be relatively simple to create an add-in that asks the user for the month (maybe even picks up the current month as a default suggestion) and does the replaces.  Across textboxes and shapes with text, pretty simple.  If you need it to delve into tables and smartart, it gets more complex; charts, something of a nightmare and inserted graphics?  Do not go there. ;-)

Comment: Hi Steve, can you point me in a direction of how to create such add-ins? I do not have Visual Studio, just VBA. I think what you offer is a potential solution to my question.

Comment: Write your code in VBA, save it first as a PPT/PPTM file, then again as a PPA/PPAM add-in.  Use PowerPoint Options, Add-ins to load it and away you go.  There's a very simplified explanation of how to do this on my PowerPoint FAQ site here:  http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00031_Create_an_ADD-IN_with_TOOLBARS_that_run_macros.htm

Comment: Thanks Steve, I will look into this in greater detail shortly.